# using security helpers does not compile : play framework 2.3.x

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

I am trying to use the security helpers inside a controller as shown in the source code of Security.scala

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Security.scala#L31

My code looks like

```
import play.mvc.Security.Authenticated

Application extends Controller {
  ..... some other Actions
  def isAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
      Authenticated { user =>
          Action(request => f(user)(request))
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting the following compilation error

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/venki/play/lrs/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/venki/play/lrs/app/controllers/Application.scala:119: object play.mvc.Security.Authenticated is not a value
[error]       Authenticated { user =>
[error]       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

I can't understand the error. From the source code i can see that Security object contains two overloaded methods named Authenticated. I have exactly copy pasted the code given as example usage, still it does not work. Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Security type you are refering to on github lies in the  `play.api.mvc` package but you are importing the one from the `play.mvc`. `play.mvc` is reserved for Java, not for Scala, [see here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaHome) for more info.

Comment: Man.. you are my life saver. You should get a medal